# Is it possible to connect automatically to a server on login without an opened window?

Tags: osx-server, network, login

I know how to have the connection established at login, but I don't know if it's possible that the Finder doesn't open a window of the server root...

I've tried the "Hide" checkbox, but this doesn't help. (I'm on Snow Leopard)

Comment: Can you define 'connect automatically'? Are you talking about establishing a connection purely for authentication reasons? What's wrong with a window popping up? How is it currently set up?

Comment: Yes, that's it, an automated mounting of different servers. What is annoying is that there are a bunch of servers that I needed the users to be connected; that makes a lot of windows opened at login...

Comment: I think you can use the mount command in terminal to mount a remote share, without having it open up in the Finder.

Comment: It's not really for me, but for all the users of my company...

Comment: I'm not making the connection.  What does it matter who it's for?

Comment: I though you meant to start the terminal to connect to the servers. I cannot ask that at my users...

Comment: Nah.  If the server connections can be established via the mount command, I would recommend you create a script to mount those servers, and then have the script get run when the users log in to their accounts, instead of having the connections established through the finder on login.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It does. Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of whatever method you are doing now to mount the server, I would recommend a script which is launched at login for all users.

Your best options are either a LoginHook or a launchd process installed to /Library/LaunchAgents/

You will then need to figure out the syntax for the mounting the drive.

UPDATE:

I decided I wanted to check this out further myself, and created this launchd script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>luoma.mount.blackbook</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/luomat/Dropbox/bin/mount_blackbook.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

which I placed at /Library/LaunchAgents/luoma.mount.blackbook.plist (owned by root)

The script  can be found at http://f.luo.ma/mount_blackbook.sh (note: script will display in browser window, to download, use click-click/save-as)

Answer (score 0):

In OS X Server, you can specify a share as an 'automount'. Is that what you had in mind?

Then, when your users authenticate against your Open Directory server, they not only see their desktop, but are automatically connected to a server sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could mount them with a simple Automator app that's added to the login items. You would just add a "Get Specified Servers" action, add the servers to it, then add a Connect to Servers action. It will mount all the specified servers without opening their windows.

When you add your servers, be sure to include the name of the share point you want to mount, something like `afp://10.0.0.1/SharePoint/`, otherwise, you'll get the "select the volumes you want to mount" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Another option (one which I haven't tried) is to disable Finder opening a new window whenever a new volume is mounted.

I believe the proper syntax is:

`defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages auto-open-ro-root -bool false`

`defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages auto-open-rw-root -bool false`

Of course this will change the behavior for more than just these particular items.